# Conditional formatting of Reactive Form Control based on control value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, reactive, formbuilder

**This is a question about formatting text based on `formControl` in an applications in which the formControls are built using `FormBuilder` and arrays of formControls.**

**It requires accessing the current value of a formControl and changing the format of another element based on that formControl value.**

I have a page in an app that is an inventory tracking form built in Ionic/Angular/Reactive.

[image]

The content comes from a database subscription.

You can see in the form that when the **Should Have** is less than **Actually Have** the format of the item changes from red to green.

This format is set using *ngIf in the template file   (See Arrows <------):

```
  <form [formGroup]="inventoryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="ident">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of inventoryElements; let i = index;">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col *ngIf="item.current < item.par" style="color: red">
              <strong>{{item.name}}</strong></ion-col           <----------
            >
            <ion-col *ngIf="item.current >= item.par" style="color: green"
              ><strong>{{item.name}}</strong></ion-col          <----------
            >
            <ion-col>{{item.par}} {{item.units}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <input size="1"
                     style="text-align: right;"
                     id="ident-{{ i }}"
                     type="text"
                     [formControlName]="i" />
              {{item.units}}
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </form>
```

(Note: I should probably update the two *ngIfs to an *ngIf-else-template, but that's not the question here.)

Of course, the color is set when the form is loaded.  If a user updates the **Actually Have** the color does not change.  **Making the color change as the `formControl` value changes is the question here.**

The form control array is built in `ngOnInit()`:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.inventoryCollection = this.afs.collection('inventory', (ref) => {
      this.query = ref;
      this.query = this.query.orderBy('category');
      return this.query;
    });

    this.inventoryInfo = this.inventoryCollection.snapshotChanges();

    this.inventoryInfo.subscribe((actionArray) => {

      // this map takes the firestore document name and makes it the ID
      this.inventoryElements = actionArray.map((item) => ({
        id: item.payload.doc.id,
        ...item.payload.doc.data(),
        expanded: false,
      }));
      //======================= Here is where the control array is built ==================
      this.ident.clear();
      actionArray.forEach(item => {
        this.ident.push(this.fb.control(item.payload.doc.data().current));
      });
      //==========================================================
    });

  }
```

(Note:  I'm sure that my clear-the array and rebuild it as the subscription emits new values is not efficient.  Happy to have suggestions there, but that's not the core question.)

What I have tried to do without success is to change the `*ngIf()` for the item colors using a formControl.get() function.  But I cannot get the proper syntax.  Here's what I tried:

```
<ion-col *ngIf="inventoryForm.get('0').value < item.par" style="color: red">
```

The '0' is there just to grab one value as I was troubleshooting.  Obviously this would change as we iterate over the `inventoryElements`.

** THE QUESTION:  What is the proper way to access the values of the controls in the `formArray` for the purpose of the comparison in the *ngIf()? **

Comment: You can use in the tag some like:`[style.color]="+formArrayName.at(i).value<item.units?'red':'green'"` -see the "+" before the formArrayName.at(i).value to convr to number. You can also use `formArrayName.value[i]`

Comment: Yes!  that was **nearly** the answer, but it put me on the right path:  The only change was in the comparison.  Final code for the ion-col was this:              `<ion-col size="6" [style.color] = "+ident.at(i).value < +item.par?'red':'green'">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eliseo had the correct answer.  the concept was to bind the [style.color] for the text to a comparison.  Take special note of the `+` prior to the parameter to make the string into a number that could be compared.

Comment: The concept of binding a style to a formatter has opened up a whole new world of ideas.